# Read Azure AD groups by Web API controller fails with 'Insufficient privileges to complete the operation'

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, adal, azure-ad-msal

I have a Web API application registered in my company's AAD. This is a multi-tenant application that is capable of querying AADs of subscribed customers. When customers subscribe to our service they register our app in their AAD's Enterprise Applications registration section and provide us with tenantId, clientId, and clientSecret. We then use these parameters to query customer's AAD.

I'm using the following to read groups from customer's Azure AD:

```
    public async Task<GraphServiceClient> CreateGraphServiceClient(string tenantId, string clientId, string clientSecret)
    {
        string aadInstance = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}";
        string resource = "https://graph.microsoft.com";
        string authority = string.Format(aadInstance, tenantId);

        AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
        ClientCredential credentials = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);
        var authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, credentials);
        if(authResult == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("GetGraphServiceClient: AcquireTokenAsync failed!");
        }

        var accessToken = authResult.AccessToken;
        var graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(
            new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
                requestMessageClientOtherTenant =>
                {
                    requestMessageClientOtherTenant.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", accessToken);
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }));

        return graphServiceClient;
    }

//....
        var graphServiceClient = CreateGraphClient(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);

        var graphGroupsPage = await graphServiceClient.Groups
            .Request()
            .Select(e => new {
                e.Id,
                e.DisplayName
            })
            .GetAsync();
```

I'm getting 'Insufficient privileges to complete the operation' error.

I've seen quite a number of workarounds on-line which were 2-3 years old but neihter of them worked for me.

The permissions granted to the app in customer's "Enterprise applications" section :
[image]

These permissions are exactly the same as permissions assigned to the app in our AAD registration.

I'm at a loss here. All required permissions seem to be granted and I'm still getting the error.

**I can use the same graph client to get all users from customer's AAD with no problems.**

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: How did you get the graphServiceClient?

Comment: Please also list the permissions under App registrations->your app->api permissioins here.

Comment: @TonyJu The api permissions are exactly the same as granted permissions. I edited the post accordingly. I added creation of graphServiceClient code to my post. I also added a comment that I have no problems retrieving all users using the same graphServiceClient.

Comment: @TonyJu I also updated my post. Hopefully I clarifed the situation a bit more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When customers subscribe to our service they register our app in their
>   AAD's Enterprise Applications registration section and provide us with
>   tenantId, clientId, and clientSecret. We then use these parameters to
>   query customer's AAD.

Since your customer has granted your multi-tenant app to access their tenant information, only customer's `tennantId` is needed, you should use your own multi-tenant app's `clientId` and `clientSecret` to access customers' AD.

If you use customer's client_id and secret, you should check the permissions under their app(not enterprise app), but, this doesn't make any sense. If so, there is no need to use your multi-tenant application.